# PHP reading a csv file effectively

Tags: php

There are a few ways to read CSV files with PHP. I used to use the *explode* function to put each line into an array and then *explode* commas and use *trim* to remove any quotation marks from around the data. It was messy...

In PHP 5 there's now *fgetcsv* and *str_getcsv*... I'm guessing this is the best way to go about it these days so I've whipped together some code...

```
$fp = fopen($csv_file['file_path'], 'r');       
while (($data = fgetcsv($fp, 0, "\r", '"', "\r")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        print_r(str_getcsv($data[$c]));
    }
}
```

It seems to work but is there a more fail safe approach? For example making it work whether line breaks are \n or \r...

Any input you can give would be awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This converts the CSV into a nested array. Might be easier for you to deal with:

```
<?php
    /**
     * 
     */
    function csv_entry_to_array(array $row)
    {
        $column_count = count($row);
        $csv_column_values = array();

        // Loop through the columns of the current CSV entry and store its value
        for ($column_index = 0; $column_index < $column_count; $column_index++)
        {
            // Store the value of the current CSV entry
            $csv_column_values[] = $row[$column_index];
        }

        // Return
        return $csv_column_values;      
    }

    /**
     * @param string    $input_file_name            Filename of input CSV
     * @param boolean   $include_header_in_output   Flag indicating whether the first entry in the CSV is included in the output or not.
     * @param integer   $length                     Must be greater than the longest line (in characters) to be found in the CSV file (allowing for trailing line-end characters).
     *                                              It became optional in PHP 5. Omitting this parameter (or setting it to 0 in PHP 5.0.4 and later) the maximum line length is
     *                                              not limited, which is slightly slower.
     * @param string    $delimeter                  Set the field delimiter (one character only).
     * @param string    $enclosure                  Set the field enclosure character (one character only).
     * @param string    $escape                     Set the escape character (one character only). Defaults as a backslash.
     * $return  array                               Nested indexed array representing the CSV. Empty array on error (e.g. input file missing, input file not a CSV).
     */
    function csv_file_to_array($input_file_name, $include_header_in_output = TRUE, $length = 1000, $delimeter = ',', $enclosure = '"', $escape = '\\')
    {
        // NOTE: this attempts to properly recognize line endings when reading files from Mac; has small performance penalty
        ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', TRUE);

        $csv_array = array();

        // Warnings are supressed, but that's OK since the code handles such warnings
        if (($handle = @fopen($input_file_name, "r")) !== FALSE)
        {
            $row_counter      = 0;

            // Iterate over the CSV entries
            while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, $length, $delimeter, $enclosure, $escape)) !== FALSE)
            {           
                if ($row_counter === 0 && $include_header_in_output === TRUE)
                {
                    // This is the first row in the CSV and it should be included in the output
                    $csv_array[] = csv_entry_to_array($row);                
                }
                else if ($row_counter > 0)
                {
                    // This is a row in the CSV that needs to be stored in the return array
                    $csv_array[] = csv_entry_to_array($row);
                }

                $row_counter++;
            }

            // Close file handler
            fclose($handle);
        }
        else
        {
            // Input file: some error occured
            return array();
        }

        return $csv_array;
    }
```

Comment: I also mentioned this to Mario above but I think maybe there's something wrong with my CSV file... Here's a coy of it bensinclair.co/import.csv... When I use this file with your code it outputs my data like what happens with marios code above img192.imageshack.us/img192/2483/screenshot20111006at123b.png I've created the CSV file in Microsoft Excel on Mac. Am I doing something wrong or does something need to be adjusted in the code?

Comment: I've updated the code. Added `        ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', TRUE);`. Give it a try.

Comment: At first I didn't use your example because I didn't went to tweak the ini settings but your solution ended up being the best especially when it comes to handling csv data correctly :)

Answer (score 6):

There is a function for reading files in line-wise: [`file()`](http://php.net/file), which also works on both linebreak types.

And the shortest method to read in the whole CSV file is:

```
$data = array_map("str_getcsv", file($filename));
```

Not sure what your `$num = count()` was about.

Comment: Hi Mario, thanks for the reply! The code you've given me puts each cell into one array instead of each line into its own array. So I now have a massive array with every cell from every line in it. Am I making sense? How do I break each line into its own array?

Comment: The above snippet would give you a two-dimensional `$data[$line][$row]`, the commonly assumed table structure. Not quite sure what you'd want instead. -- If you only wanted to look at each line once, then use a foreach instead: `foreach (file($fn) as $line) { $data = str_getcsv($line); }`

Comment: I think maybe there's something wrong with my CSV file... Here's a coy of it http://bensinclair.co/import.csv... When I use this file with your code it outputs my data like this http://img192.imageshack.us/img192/2483/screenshot20111006at123b.png

Comment: Oh. In this case, I'm wrong. The `file()` function does not react well to the Mac-style line endings. Manually split up the file using: `$file = preg_split('/[\r\n]+/', file_get_contents($filename))` instead. Then use foreach or the array_map/str_getcsv approach.

Comment: Legend! So I presume if they import a Windows or any other line break (if any) it will also work? Thanks for your help!