# Issues in iterating the below php code

Tags: php, html

Hi I have the Below PHP and HTML code Which Reads the CSV file and List the 4 rows of CSV file as Link in HTML.I want to make the below code as dynamic through iteration.How can I do it.As I am Novice in Php I am stuck over here.

Below is the Snippet of PHP code

```
<?php
    function readCSV($fileName) {
      $rows = array();
      $rows = file($fileName);
      return $rows;
}   ?>

  <span><b>Available Positions: </b></span>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#<?php print_r(readCSV('joinUs.csv')[1]);?>"><?php print_r(readCSV('joinUs.csv')[1]);?></a></li>
    <li>|</li>
    <li><a href="#<?php print_r(readCSV('joinUs.csv')[2]);?>"><?php print_r(readCSV('joinUs.csv')[2]);?></a></li>
    <li>|</li>
    <li><a href="#<?php print_r(readCSV('joinUs.csv')[3]);?>"><?php print_r(readCSV('joinUs.csv')[3]);?></a></li>
    <li>|</li>
    <li><a href="#<?php print_r(readCSV('joinUs.csv')[4]);?>"><?php print_r(readCSV('joinUs.csv')[4]); ?></a></li>
  </ul>
```

**joinUs.csv** file

```
Available Position
Sr. Product Engineer
Quality Assurance Engineer
Frontend Javascript Engineer
Business Development Manager
```

**Displayed as** 
[image]

Please Help me in making the Above code Dynamic Instead for Hardcoing the arrays as 1,2,3,4 in href tag.

Thanks in Advance
Rahul Jain

Comment: See the manual for how to do this with [fgetcsv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP reading a csv file effectively](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669859/php-reading-a-csv-file-effectively)

Comment: No Its not Duplicate as I am facing issue with integrating with href tags

Comment: I don't think you have a grasp on what file() is returning or how to loop through the results.

Answer (score 1):

Read the CSV file into an array (like you're doing, but only once). Then loop through the array using `foreach()`. There is an example in the PHP documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: But How to make a href tag dynamic.

Comment: Did you read the documentation on the page I linked?

Comment: Yes I have gone through it But The main Issue is in integrating with href tag and I am unable to find in it

Comment: you see the $value in all those examples? that's what you'll use instead of all that `print_r(readCSV('joinUs.csv')[2])` mess that you have now

Answer (score 1):

[https://www.php.net/fgetcsv](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.fgetcsv.php)

You should open a file (with fopen function), then you can use the fgetcsv method to fetch a line from your csv as an array.
Use a loop to iterate over every line.

```
    $file = fopen($fileName, "r");
    
    while ($row = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ' ')) {
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach ($row as $element) {
            echo "<li>$element</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
    
    fclose($file);
```

Comment: Hi You have told about the Iteration Part But How do I make the Html list tag dynamic                                                     <li><a href="#<?php print_r(readCSV('joinUs.csv')[1]);?>"><?php print_r(readCSV('joinUs.csv')[1]);?></a></li>

Comment: $row is an array, you can go through each of its element with a simple foreach loop (i'll edit the answer).

Comment: Hi Can I add a href tag in the echo inside forEach loop in the above mentioned code to display the link dynamically.I am new to PHP and I just want to know whether we can add Html a ref inside php.

Comment: PHP will generate the HTML you echo, so yes, you can use <a href...> or any other tag you want.